# Determining if a process is running

Tags: powershell, blat

all,

I am new to Power Shell scripting and my second script is not working 100%. I am not sure what is going on.

Purpose:

1. Check to see if a specific process is running or not.
2. If it is running, send an email advising.
3. If it is not running, attempt to start the process.
4. If attempting to start the process, recheck to see if process started or not.

Issue:

- If I change the directory location of the script (to make sure it is wrong), I get the right email.
- If the process is running, I get the right email.
- If the process is not running, the script starts the process correctly, but sends and email saying the process is not running when in fact it is running.

Script:

```
# Date and Date/Time stamping for files and logs.
$FileDateTimeStamp = get-date -uformat "%m%d%Y-%H%M%S"
$FileDateStamp = get-date -uformat "%m%d%Y"

# Logs directory.
$LogsDirectory = "C:\logs\"

# AS2 file information.
$AS2 = "C:\Program Files\nsoftware\AS2 Connector V2\as2app\bin\nsoftware.AS2Connector.exe"
$AS2ParentDirectory = "C:\Program Files\nsoftware\AS2 Connector V2"
$ProcessNameToCheck = "nsoftware.AS2Connector"
$ProcessIsRunning = Get-Process $ProcessNameToCheck -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$StartTheProcess = start-process -filepath $AS2
$SleepTime = 2

# Exchange information for sending emails.
$EmailServer = "email.me.com"
$EmailFrom = "me@me.com"
$AuthUser = "username"
$AuthPass = "password"
$EmailPort = 25
$MaxRetries = 1

# Blat log file location/name.
$BlatLogFile = $LogsDirectory + "BlatLog-" + $FileDateStamp + ".log"

# Blat information.
#$EmailTo = "smaguire@varietydistributors.com,abarnes@varietydistributors.com,tmalcom@varietydistributors.com"
$EmailTo = "smaguire@varietydistributors.com"
$EmailToSubjectSuccess = "AS2 Connector is running."
$EmailToBodySuccess = "The process check for AS2 Connector on OSPC was successful. AS2 Connector is running."
$EmailToSubjectFail = "AS2 Connector is NOT running."
$EmailToBodyFail = "The process check for AS2 Connector on OSPC was unsuccessful. Attempted to start the application which was also unsuccessful. AS2 Connector is NOT currently running on OSPC."
$EmailToSubjectNotInstalled = "AS2 Connector Installation Not Found."
$EmailToBodyNotInstalled = "The process check for AS2 Connector on OSPC failed because AS2 Connector does not seem to be installed."
$XHeaderInfo = "Email sent from OSPC"

function WriteLogFile {
    #Code snippet obtained from: http://poshcode.org/2566

    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $Message,

        [Parameter()] [ValidateSet(“Error”, “Warn”, “Info”)]
        [string] $Level = “Info”,

        [Parameter()] [ValidateRange(1,30)]
        [Int16] $Indent = 0,

        [Parameter()]
        [IO.FileInfo] $ScriptLogFile = $LogsDirectory + "ScriptLog-" + $FileDateStamp + ".log",

        [Parameter()]
        [Switch] $Clobber,

        [Parameter()]
        [String] $EventLogName,

        [Parameter()]
        [String] $EventSource = ([IO.FileInfo] $MyInvocation.ScriptName).Name,

        [Parameter()]
        [Int32] $EventID = 1
    )

    Begin {}

    Process {
        try {           
            $msg = '{0}{1} : {2} : {3}' -f (" " * $Indent), (Get-Date -Format “yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss”), $Level.ToUpper(), $Message

            switch ($Level) {
                'Error' { Write-Error $Message }
                'Warn' { Write-Warning $Message }
                'Info' { Write-Host ('{0}{1}' -f (" " * $Indent), $Message) -ForegroundColor White}
            }

            if ($Clobber) {
                $msg | Out-File -FilePath $ScriptLogFile
            } else {
                $msg | Out-File -FilePath $ScriptLogFile -Append
            }

            if ($EventLogName) {
                if(-not [Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($EventSource)) { 
                    [Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource($EventSource, $EventLogName) 
                } 
                $log = New-Object System.Diagnostics.EventLog  
                $log.set_log($EventLogName)  
                $log.set_source($EventSource) 

                switch ($Level) {
                    “Error” { $log.WriteEntry($Message, 'Error', $EventID) }
                    “Warn”  { $log.WriteEntry($Message, 'Warning', $EventID) }
                    “Info”  { $log.WriteEntry($Message, 'Information', $EventID) }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            throw “Failed to create log entry in: ‘$ScriptLogFile’. The error was: ‘$_’.”
        }
    }

    End {}
}

if (test-path $AS2ParentDirectory) {
    # AS2 is installed on this machine.
    # Check for the running process.
    if (!($ProcessIsRunning)) {
        # Process is not found = not runing.
        # Try to start the process.
        # Once start attempt is complete, recheck to make sure failed or succeeded.
        # Failed: send an alert email through blat.
        # Succeeded: Send an alert email through blat.
        write-host "AS2 Connector is not running. Attempting to start."
        WriteLogFile -message "Script Line #142: AS2 Conenctor is not running. Attempting to start." -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        $StartTheProcess

        # Give the process a little time to start before checking. Wait X seconds.
        write-host "Going to sleep for $SleepTime seconds."
        WriteLogFile -message "Script Line #147: Going to sleep for $SleepTime seconds." -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        start-sleep -s $SleepTime

            # Now, let's go ahead and recheck to see if the process started or not.
            if (!($ProcessIsRunning)) {
                # Process did not start successfully.
                write-host "AS2 Connector did not start successfully. Sending an email to advise."
                WriteLogFile -message "Script Line #162: AS2 Conenctor did not start successfully. Sending an email to advise." -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
                WriteLogFile -message "Sending an email to: $EmailTo" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
                WriteLogFile -message "Email Subject: $EmailToSubjectFail" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
                WriteLogFile -message "Email Body: $EmailToBodyFail" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
                C:\blat\blat.exe -to $EmailTo -s $EmailToSubjectFail -i $EmailFrom -body $EmailToBodyFail -server $EmailServer -f $EmailFrom -u $AuthUser -pw $AuthPass -port $EmailPort -try $MaxRetries -debug -log $BlatLogFile -timestamp -x $XHeaderInfo
            } else {
                # Process started successfully.
                write-host "AS2 Connector started successfully. Sending an email to advise."
                WriteLogFile -message "Script Line #154: AS2 Conenctor started successfully. Sending an email to advise." -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
                WriteLogFile -message "Sending an email to: $EmailTo" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
                WriteLogFile -message "Email Subject: $EmailToSubjectSuccess" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
                WriteLogFile -message "Email Body: $EmailToBodySuccess" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
                C:\blat\blat.exe -to $EmailTo -s $EmailToSubjectSuccess -i $EmailFrom -body $EmailToBodySuccess -server $EmailServer -f $EmailFrom -u $AuthUser -pw $AuthPass -port $EmailPort -try $MaxRetries -debug -log $BlatLogFile -timestamp -x $XHeaderInfo            
            }
    } else {
        # Process is found = running.
        # Send an email advising of running status.
        write-host "Verified AS2 Connector is running. Sending an email to advise."
        WriteLogFile -message "Script Line #130: Verified AS2 Conenctor is running. Sending an email to advise." -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        WriteLogFile -message "Sending an email to: $EmailTo" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        WriteLogFile -message "Email Subject: $EmailToSubjectSuccess" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        WriteLogFile -message "Email Body: $EmailToBodySuccess" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        C:\blat\blat.exe -to $EmailTo -s $EmailToSubjectSuccess -i $EmailFrom -body $EmailToBodySuccess -server $EmailServer -f $EmailFrom -u $AuthUser -pw $AuthPass -port $EmailPort -try $MaxRetries -debug -log $BlatLogFile -timestamp -x $XHeaderInfo
    }
} else {
    # AS2 is not installed on this machine.
    # Send an email advising that there is a potential problem.
    write-host "AS2 Connector does not seem to be installed or is corrupt. Sending an email to advise."
    WriteLogFile -message "Script Line #173: AS2 Conenctor does not seem to be installed or is corrupt. Sending an email to advise." -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
    WriteLogFile -message "Sending an email to: $EmailTo" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
    WriteLogFile -message "Email Subject: $EmailToSubjectNotInstalled" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
    WriteLogFile -message "Email Body: $EmailToBodyNotInstalled" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
    C:\blat\blat.exe -to $EmailTo -s $EmailToSubjectNotInstalled -i $EmailFrom -body $EmailToBodyNotInstalled -server $EmailServer -f $EmailFrom -u $AuthUser -pw $AuthPass -port $EmailPort -try $MaxRetries -debug -log $BlatLogFile -timestamp -x $XHeaderInfo
}
```

The portion of code that is going wrong is:

```
    # Now, let's go ahead and recheck to see if the process started or not.
    if (!($ProcessIsRunning)) {
        # Process did not start successfully.
        write-host "AS2 Connector did not start successfully. Sending an email to advise."
        WriteLogFile -message "Script Line #162: AS2 Conenctor did not start successfully. Sending an email to advise." -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        WriteLogFile -message "Sending an email to: $EmailTo" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        WriteLogFile -message "Email Subject: $EmailToSubjectFail" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        WriteLogFile -message "Email Body: $EmailToBodyFail" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        C:\blat\blat.exe -to $EmailTo -s $EmailToSubjectFail -i $EmailFrom -body $EmailToBodyFail -server $EmailServer -f $EmailFrom -u $AuthUser -pw $AuthPass -port $EmailPort -try $MaxRetries -debug -log $BlatLogFile -timestamp -x $XHeaderInfo
    } else {
        # Process started successfully.
        write-host "AS2 Connector started successfully. Sending an email to advise."
        WriteLogFile -message "Script Line #154: AS2 Conenctor started successfully. Sending an email to advise." -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        WriteLogFile -message "Sending an email to: $EmailTo" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        WriteLogFile -message "Email Subject: $EmailToSubjectSuccess" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        WriteLogFile -message "Email Body: $EmailToBodySuccess" -level Info -EventID 3 -Indent 2 -EventLogName 'Application' -EventSource "AS2Check.ps1"
        C:\blat\blat.exe -to $EmailTo -s $EmailToSubjectSuccess -i $EmailFrom -body $EmailToBodySuccess -server $EmailServer -f $EmailFrom -u $AuthUser -pw $AuthPass -port $EmailPort -try $MaxRetries -debug -log $BlatLogFile -timestamp -x $XHeaderInfo            
    }
```

Comment: Please, use a title that ***describes*** your problem. You'll have more chances of people looking at it. Right now, it's meaningless, unattractive and prone to downvotes.

Comment: @b__ is right. Your title will not encourage people to look. Your problem is that after you try to restart the process, you never again set the value of $ProcessIsRunning. So your script thinks the process is not running whether it is or not.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will do so next time.

Comment: @EBGreen I tried to do if ($ProcessIsRunning -eq $true) and even that didn't work.

Comment: $ProcessIsRunning will still be false from the first time you checked. You need to check again after you start it.

Comment: My answer should solve your problems.  If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Of course, @b__ has enough rep to fix the title too :)

Comment: @EBGreen, not my field of work, I thought of using part of your comment, but am not really sure...

Comment: @b__ just click the edit button and edit the title.

Comment: If you are using powershell 3.0 or newer there is a send-mailmessage cmdlet to send mail directly from powershell.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ProcessIsRunning = Get-Process $ProcessNameToCheck -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$StartTheProcess = start-process -filepath $AS2
```

When you run these lines, the commands are executed immediately, and the result is stored in the variable. So if the process was not running at the beginning of the script, `$ProcessIsRunning` will always be null (not running).

The solution is to remove both lines at the top, and replace every instance of the following variables below in your script:

- `$ProcessIsRunning` with `(Get-Process $ProcessNameToCheck -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)`. Ex. `if(!(Get-Process $ProcessNameToCheck -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) { "not running" } else { "running" }`.
- `$StartTheProcess` with `Start-Process -Filepath $AS2`

You could also try this approach, which is probably what you original plan was:

```
$ProcessIsRunning = { Get-Process notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
$StartTheProcess = { Start-Process notepad }

#Run the start-process command
$StartTheProcess.Invoke()

#This will run the get-process command whenever you call it by using the Invoke() method.
if(!$ProcessIsRunning.Invoke()) {
    "Not running"
} else {
    "Running"
}
```

Ouput:

```
Running
```

Answer (score 0):

This `$StartTheProcess = start-process -filepath $AS2` saves the results of running start-process.  If you have a line of code in your script that says `$StartTheProcess` (as you do) don't expect it to run a command; it will only display the output that was saved originally.

Either call `start-process` at the appropriate location, or use a function.

Edit: As a comment said, (and I missed) you also need to recheck whether the process is running.  Rerun this line before you check the second time.

```
$ProcessIsRunning = Get-Process $ProcessNameToCheck -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```